# Stretch a text box the full width of the page with a 5px margin

Tags: html, css, input, width, margin

I'm creating a simple HTML document containing a form that I intend to use as the contents of a [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) within a Firefox add-on. At present the document contains a label and text box, and I want this to stretch the full width of the page with a margin of 5px either side. This my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Phrase Indexer</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
  body {
    font: 10pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div {
    width: inherit
  }
  #phrase {
    width: inherit;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<label for="phrase">Passphrase</label><br />
<input type="text" id="phrase" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This mostly works, except I'm missing a 5px margin on the right - the text box stretches right to the edge of the page. How can I fix this?

[Here's a Fiddle of my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/NgXjW/)

Comment: I added a Fiddle, so people can demonstrate their answers to you.

Comment: Position `fixed`? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bUq32/

Comment: @dfsq: I think your fiddle has it.  Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @dfsq: Yup, you're answer has done. Go ahead and post an answer, and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
body
{
   font: 10pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div
{
    padding: 0.5em;
}

div > *
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/utabul/1

---

More on this here: [Set CSS 100% Width Minus Padding And Margin](http://www.ikelin.com/set-css-width-100-percent-minus-padding-and-margin/)

Comment: This one is even better! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Just learned about this today! Thanks for posting the question... :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try out box-sizing. I just adding the margin to the div that wraps the form elements, removed the position from the body and add box-sizing to the input.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */


body {
  font: 10pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  /* position: fixed; */
}
div {
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
#phrase {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems the most elegant so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Phrase Indexer</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
  *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  body {
  }
  div {
  }
  #phrase {
    width: 100%;
    margin:5px;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<label for="phrase">Passphrase</label><br />
<input type="text" id="phrase" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix it, though.  Instead, this makes the page scroll to the right.  Here it is in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgXjW/1/

Comment: Yes, you're right. The right way: *{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div{
    padding:0px 7px 0 5px;
}


 #phrase {
    width: 100%;
  }


The 7px padding instead of 5px is because of the border of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the body padding: 5px instead of margin, get rid of the fixed position and set the div width to 100% instead of the body - http://jsfiddle.net/xX8yA

```
body {
font: 10pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 5px;
}
div {
width: 100%;
}
#phrase {
width: inherit;
}
```